# What's the equivalent of md5sum --check for a mac?

Tags: macos, security, data-transfer, authentication

I have a lot of files that I need to check.  In a UNIX environment I can simply type:

```
md5sum --check MD5.txt
```

and the checksum of each file is calculated and compared against the checksums in MD5.txt.  How do I do this in a macOS environment.  The closest I found was to run

```
md5 -r * > output.txt
```

but then I have to manually compare the checksums against the MD5.txt file.

Is there anyway to do this checkup automatically?

Comment: I prefer `shasum` which does have a `-c` option for checking.  But needs a script to build the check file for all files in a directory tree.

Comment: Try `md5 -r * | diff -w MD5.txt -`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're open to installing Homebrew formulae, `rhash` and/or `md5sum` (part of the **coreutils** package) will do the job:

```bash
brew install rhash coreutils
```

Then:

```bash
rhash --md5 --recursive --output=/tmp/md5.txt /path/to/hash

rhash --check --skip-ok /tmp/md5.txt
```

Or:

```bash
find /path/to/hash -type f -exec md5sum {} \; >/tmp/md5.txt 

md5sum --check --quiet /tmp/md5.txt
```

Omit the `--skip-ok` or `--quiet` flags if you want *all* filenames to be output during verification, otherwise only mismatched ones will be printed.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the openssl command (included with MacOS) to create a checksum.

For instance, to create an sha256 checksum:

`openssl dgst -sha256 <filename>`

To create an md5 checksum:

`openssl md5 <filename>`

Answer (score 3):

You can install this the [Microbrew MD5sum/SHA1sum/RIPEMD160sum](http://microbrew.org/tools/md5sha1sum/) utility that includes the md5sum tool.  It's available with [Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/md5sha1sum):

```
brew install md5sha1sum
```